# Reimport working set in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I accidentally clicked "remove" on a working set (I only wished to hide it).

Is there a way I can re-import the working set into Eclipse or is my code deleted?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working set is just a view, it wont have deleted your project code from the disk if you only did "remove" from the working set window. If you change your working set to "Window Working Set" (the default) you should be able to see your projects in there, then just reassign them to a new set.

If they aren't there, you might need to re-import them from your workspace directory.